# Is the mySQL query SELECT * okay?

Tags: mysql, select

I select my query with

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xy WHERE id='$_POST[ID]'", $mysqlconnect1);
$logindat = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Is there any improvement when I call "SELECT XY FROM"?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise, there won't be any difference. However, there might be some network traffic if you are fetching too many rows and table have massive number of columns. If you are interested in only a few columns, recommended approach is to use the column names in the query.

Also, performance will depend on whether there is any `index` on `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no difference in performance from * to each column name. * will internally resolve to each column name. It will be helpful to have reduced number of column in select clause only if there are aggregation functions involved.